# Pivoting and viewing values in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I am trying to get my SQL output in the format below.
[image: Expected Output]

I am able to get the following output from POSTGRESQL

[image: Output I am getting]

How can I pivot this and add a 'Year' column that classifies the row as 'Last Year' or 'Current Year' and assigns the value appropriately?

The code I have is:

```
Select Sales_Group, Sum(Last_Jul), Sum(Last_Aug), Sum(Current_Jul), Sum(Current_Aug)
FROM MKT_SALES_DATA
where Sales_Group = 'G1'
GROUP by Sales_Group
```

Any advice on how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, post sample data in a text form, not as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH T 
(
  "GROUP"
, LAST_JUL
, LAST_AUG
, CURRENT_JUL
, CURRENT_AUG
)
AS
(
  VALUES
    ('G1', 500, 300, 800, 500)
)
SELECT T."GROUP", V.YEAR, V.JUL, V.AUGUST
FROM T
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
  VALUES
    ('Last Year', T.LAST_JUL, T.LAST_AUG)
  , ('Current Year', T.CURRENT_JUL, T.CURRENT_AUG)
) V (YEAR, JUL, AUGUST)
```

| GROUP | year | jul | august |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | Last Year | 500 | 300 |
| G1 | Current Year | 800 | 500 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fAZDfcy8)